# ASP.NET Impersonation not working on production

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, impersonation

So I've an issue with code on a production server, running Windows Server 2003 & IIS 6.

I'm trying to impersonate a domain account, which works fine locally.

Though when it's on the server the function impersonate user fails, i.e returns false:

```
private bool impersonateValidUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (RevertToSelf())
        {
            if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                {
                    tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                    impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    if (impersonationContext != null)
                    {
                        CloseHandle(token);
                        CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(token);
        if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
        return false;
    }
```

Note, the code doesn't crash - it just returns false. Has anyone experienced this before and have any ideas of what I should start looking at? I assuming IIS configuration is at play here, but it could take weeks to find a small problem causing this.

I can use the account I'm trying to impersonate to mount a drive on the server so the account user/password combo is fine and can be used to authenticate in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Which version of IIS and Windows Server please? Note that you have to perform a variety of steps to allow delegation, the most common that people forget to do is allow the "permission" the server itself for delegation in Active Directory. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810572 for an overview.

Comment: 2003 & IIS 6 - good catch I'll add to the question too.

Comment: @dash The website doesn't use windows impersonation normally, as it's external facing - but I use this for doing one off authentication to bring a file back from a shared drive.

Comment: Do you know which line isn't working? Also, for the purposes of validation, all you need is LogonUserA? All you need to know is if the username and password are valid, rather than if they can be impersonated?

Comment: Oh the code works fine, locally, on the server it attempts the validation but comes back false. I'm just not sure what I should be looking at on the server to get it working.

Comment: You need to know what line :-). If possible, add some logging, as there are several `if` statements that could be returning false. It may be that `LogonUserA` or `DuplicateToken` don't work. Is your other server where the code works internet facing? To validate the username and password, the internet server must be able to connect to the domain's Active Directory controller. Sorry for all the questions, just trying to establish what the problem potentially might be.

Answer (score 0):

I remember, I have the same Problem in a Project that impersonating don't work with the integrated mode the solution for that problem was to add to our web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

But with this impersonating doesn't work in the global.asax methods:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Hope this help you too, because I have no idea on which ISS version this was.

Comment: I have the same setting already in my web.config sadly, thanks for the answer though.

Comment: hm :/ this may helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Why is this the answer if your comment says otherwise.. ?